# How do I include new lines in a string in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, newline

I have a string that looks like this

```
Acanthocolla_cruciata,#8B5F65Acanthocyrta_haeckeli,#8B5F65Acanthometra_fusca,#8B5F65Acanthopeltis_japonica,#FFB5C5
```

I am trying to added in new lines so get in list format. Like this

```
Acanthocolla_cruciata,#8B5F65
Acanthocyrta_haeckeli,#8B5F65
Acanthometra_fusca,#8B5F65
Acanthopeltis_japonica,#FFB5C5
```

I have a perl script

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $new_tree_fh, '>', 'test_match.txt'
  or die qq{Failed to open "update_color.txt" for output: $!\n};
open my $file,  '<', $ARGV[0]
  or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[0]" for input: $!\n};

while ( my $string = <$file> ) {
    my $splitmessage = join ("\n", ($string =~ m/(.+)+\,+\#+\w{6}/gs));

    print $new_tree_fh $splitmessage, "\n";
}

close $file;
close $new_tree_fh;
```

The pattern match works but it wont print the new line as I want to make the list. Can anyone please suggest anything.

Comment: I'm not sure your pattern match actually does work there. You're using a greedy capture with `(.+)` which will eat up most of your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do:

```
my $str = 'Acanthocolla_cruciata,#8B5F65Acanthocyrta_haeckeli,#8B5F65Acanthometra_fusca,#8B5F65Acanthopeltis_japonica,#FFB5C5';
$str =~ s/(?<=,#\w{6})/\n/g;
say $str;
```

**Output:**

```
Acanthocolla_cruciata,#8B5F65
Acanthocyrta_haeckeli,#8B5F65
Acanthometra_fusca,#8B5F65
Acanthopeltis_japonica,#FFB5C5
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think your problem here is that your regular expression doesn't match properly.

```
(.+)+
```

for example - probably doesn't do what you think it does. It's a greedy capture of 1 or more of "anything" which will grab your whole string.

Check it out on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pG0jQ0/1).

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
while ( my $string = <DATA> ) {
    my $splitmessage = join( "\n", ( $string =~ m/(\w+,\#+\w{6})/g ) );
    print $splitmessage, "\n";
}

__DATA__
Acanthocolla_cruciata,#8B5F65Acanthocyrta_haeckeli,#8B5F65Acanthometra_fusca,#8B5F65Acanthopeltis_japonica,#FFB5C5
```

Which will print:

```
Acanthocolla_cruciata,#8B5F65
Acanthocyrta_haeckeli,#8B5F65
Acanthometra_fusca,#8B5F65
Acanthopeltis_japonica,#FFB5C5
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a quickfix solution, let's find the problem in your existing code and hence learn from it. Your problem is in the regular expression, so we'll dissect and fix it.

```
($string =~ m/(.+)+\,+\#+\w{6}/gs)
```

- First, the two **significant** mistakes that lead to the bug:

  1. At the beginning, you're doing a `.+`, followed by matching with `,` and `#` and so on. The problem is, `.+` is greedy, which means it'll match upto the **last** `,` in the input, and not the first one. So when you run this, almost the entire line (except for the  last plant's color) gets matched up by this single `.+`.
     There are a few different ways you can fix this, but the easiest is to restrict what you're matching. Instead of saying `.+` "match anything", make it `[\w\s]+` at the beginning - which means match either "word characters" (which includes alphabets and digits) or space characters (since there is a space in the middle of the plant name).
     `($string =~ m/([\w\s]+)+\,+\#+\w{6}/gs)`
     That changes the output, but still not to the fully correct version because:
  2. `m/some regex/g` returns a list of its matches as a list here, and what we want is for it to return the whole match including both plant name and color. But, when there are paranthesis inside the match anywhere, `m/` returns only the part matched by the paranthesis (which is the plant name here), not the whole match. So, remove the paranthesis, and it becomes:
     `($string =~ m/[\w\s]++\,+\#+\w{6}/gs)`

This works, but is quite clumsy and bug-prone, so here's some improvement suggestions:

- Since your input has no newline characters, the /s at the end is unnecessary.
  `($string =~ m/[\w\s]++\,+\#+\w{6}/g)`
- `,` and `#` are not a special character in perl regular expressions, so they don't need a `\` before them.
  `($string =~ m/[\w\s]++,+#+\w{6}/g)`
- `+` is for when you know only that the character will be present, but don't know how many times it'll be there. Here, since we're only trying to match *one* `,` and *one* `#` characters, the `+` after them is unnecessary.
  `($string =~ m/[\w\s]++,#\w{6}/g)`
- The `++` after [\w\s] means something quite different from `+` (basically an even greedier match than usual), so let's make it a single `+`
  `($string =~ m/[\w\s]+,#\w{6}/g)`
- Optionally, you can change the last `\w` to match only the hexadecimal characters which will appear in the colour code:
  `($string =~ m/[\w\s]+,#[0-9A-F]{6}/g)`

That's a pretty solid, working regular expression that does what you want.